# Disable sorting when specific header is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using this code

```
var oTable = $('#tbl').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ],
        "aoColumns": [
    null,
    null],
        "sDom": 'R<>rt<ilp><"clear">',
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "processing.php",
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        var id = aData[0];
        $(nRow).attr("id", id);
        // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
        if (aData[0] != 0) {
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<input type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="' + aData[0] + '" />');
        }

    });
return nRow;
}
});
```

When table displays i want to sort if by desc,this is ok.But when i click on checkbox to select all check boxes infornt of each row,it sort again and check becomes uncheck....
Can i remove that sorting when some one click on header checkbox?
I know that common sorting can be disable by this way,but its not my requirements

```
{ "bSortable": false },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function of the click event for the checkbox to prevent the click from registering on the table header cell as well. Calling stopPropagation() prevents the event from bubbling up to parent elements, so the table header cell won't know you clicked on it, and it won't re-sort.

It would be something like this:

```
$('th input').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```